# Custom Address Search iOS mapkit

Tags: ios

Learning swift 2/ Xcode 7 and creating a app iOS 9 where I can enter a custom address. I have mapkit working and can search regular address. I have my current location working. Instead of entering an address: "Number,Street, city, zip code", I want the user to enter: PR33.1 for example, and that would show the user that location.  I have the long and lats for the custom address's, I've read many things on geocoding and annotations but nothing that would let me accomplish what I need.  Can this be done? jSon file maybe.. I'm really new at this...
thanks

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!



let arbitraryString: [String:String] =
["161 RL2": "23908709138882,-106.7433588579297",
"40.9 RL112":"32.393144,-106.727762"]


@IBAction func enterButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
            if let textField = arbitraryString["161 RL2"] {
              print(" \(textField).")
            } else {
            print("That is not in the dictionary.")
       }


}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "custom address?" What kind of address is "PR33.1"? That doesn't look like any kind of address or map coordinate I've ever seen. Or are you saying that you have a table of arbitrary strings like "PR33.1" and lat/longs that match those strings?

Comment: You could create your own text field and match inputs to a dictionary that maps bookmark names to lat long coordinates. Also, what is "PR33.1"?

Comment: Yes Duncan that would be a better way of putting it. " A table of arbitrary strings like PR33.1. I used "custom address" because the user would be entering that in the address search field.

Comment: CrazyPython PR33.1 is an arbitrary string :)  I will look into your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: This is the code I have. When I tap on the enter button, the debug area prints out  23908709138882,-106.7433588579297.  That is a longitude and latitude that is in the arbitraryString dictionary.  Even if I don't enter anything in the textField I get that in the debug area when I click the Enter button. I never get the message "That is not in the dictionary.